# LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage returns 0xc00000fe

Tags: windows, authentication

I'm implementing a credential provider, and inside the credential's method there is this function to look for the correct authentication package to use

```
 HRESULT RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(ULONG * pulAuthPackage)
  {
    HRESULT hr;
    HANDLE hLsa;
  
    NTSTATUS status = LsaConnectUntrusted(&hLsa);
    if (SUCCEEDED(HRESULT_FROM_NT(status)))
    {
  
      ULONG ulAuthPackage;
      LSA_STRING lsaszKerberosName;
      LsaInitString(&lsaszKerberosName, NEGOSSP_NAME);
  
      status = LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(hLsa, &lsaszKerberosName, &ulAuthPackage);
      if (SUCCEEDED(HRESULT_FROM_NT(status)))
      {
        *pulAuthPackage = ulAuthPackage;
        hr = S_OK;
      }
      else
      {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);
      }
      LsaDeregisterLogonProcess(hLsa);
    }
    else
    {
      hr= HRESULT_FROM_NT(status);
    }
  
    return hr;
  }
```

When I call the API LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage, it returns 0xc00000fe (an error). Here is the values of the parameters I got from debugging:

```
hLsa (it can vary each time)     0x00391c60
lsaszKerberosName                L"Negotiate"
```

Does anyone know what possibly causes this? And what to do to fix it? Thanks :)

Comment: `L"Negotiate"` this is error - must be `NEGOSSP_NAME_A`

Comment: then code very not optimal. you not need separate `HRESULT hr` and `ULONG ulAuthPackage` have, not need sevaral times use `HRESULT_FROM_NT` but only once on return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to ms api doc, the package name parameter is defined by the following macros:

```
MSV1_0_PACKAGE_NAME

MICROSOFT_KERBEROS_NAME_A

NEGOSSP_NAME_A
```

the macro defines the type of the authentication package that you want to use
and furthermore, you must use the ascii type intead of unicode
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsalookupauthenticationpackage